# Embed external CSS class styles into SVG elements using Inkscape

Tags: css, svg, inkscape

I use Inkscape to edit existing SVG files like this one (simplified, for readability purposes):

```
<svg>
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#AFAA96;stroke:#AFAA96;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:none;stroke:#738282;stroke-width:16;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<rect x="0.5" y="0.5" class="st0" width="99" height="99"/>
<path class="st1" d="M10 10"/>
</svg>
```

As you can see, there are 2 css classes "st0" and "st1", applied to a `<rect>` and a `<path>`

I don't want the SVG to contain CSS classes.

I need that every SVG element contains all the corresponding styles of the associated class.

Is there a way, using Inkscape, to transform (automatically) the previous SVG into this ?

```
<svg>
  <rect x="0.5" y="0.5" width="99" height="99" fill="#AFAA96" stroke="#AFAA96" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
  <path fill="none" stroke="#738282" stroke-width="16" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M10 10"/>
</svg>
```

Thankyou in advance :)

Comment: I think you can use [svgo](https://github.com/svg/svgo) to do that if you specify the right options.

Comment: @RobertLongson thanks for the suggestion, but i need something with a GUI :)

Comment: Then you're asking in the wrong place.

Comment: Would File > Save as > Optimized SVG contain the options you need?

Comment: I tried, but that options seems to be very buggy

Answer (score 0):

Current solution inside inkscape:

1. select all
2. cut
3. paste (now all objs will get direct styling)
4. remove linked CSS styles from selected objects in CSS dialog
5. when all objects unlinked from any styles, you can remove empty styles.

Comment: Your answer is little confusing. User don't want the SVG to contain CSS classes.
And you are saying even though by using Inkspace it leaves classes. Please go through question once again and then edit your answer accordingly.